# custom cassandra / cqlsh time_format

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

System:

CentOS 6.7 x86_64
cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.1 | CQL spec 3.3.0

I'm having problem inserting (copy csv file) timestamp field with the format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' ,

This format not supported by default, so I've created it manually in the ~/.cassandra/cqlshrc file:

```
[ui]
time_format = %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S
```

and started cqlsh again, but I'm still unable to insert:

```
system@cqlsh> insert into nir.nir_test (END_DATE) values ('01-09-2015 18:55:50');
```

`InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '01-09-2015 18:55:50' to a formatted date (long)"`

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The `[ui]` configuration in `cqlshrc` only affects the output format. It gets applied when you query a timestamp column. For example:

```
select END_DATE from nir.nir_test;
```

Might output:

```
 end_date
---------------------
 01-09-2015 18:55:50
```

But for insertion, you need to use one of the [specified formats](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html). For example:

```
insert into nir.nir_test (END_DATE) values ('2015-09-01 18:55:50');
```

This probably means that you'll need to convert the timestamps in the CSV file before trying to insert them.