# How to import column value in Cassandra like one having such values "13/01/09 23:13"?

Tags: database, cassandra, cloud, distributed

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "TEMP_tmp".temp (
"Date_Time" timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ("Date_Time")
);
```

CSV Contains "13/01/09 23:13" values.

```
Error : Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 13/01/09 23:13 : invalid literal for long() with base 10: '13/01/09 23:13',  given up without retries.
```

What Data Type should I Use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default Cqlsh timestamp format is : year-month-day hour:min:sec+timezone
Example :

```
2017-02-01 05:28:36+0000
```

You either change your date format to above or you can change the format from cqlshrc file
Check this answer [custom cassandra / cqlsh time_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496272/custom-cassandra-cqlsh-time-format)

Comment: I already have data in Excel Sheet with "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss". Error I am receiving is  **Failed to parse  2009-08-11 15:53:00 : can't interpret ' 2009-08-11 15:53:00' as a date with format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z**

Comment: I am using "cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.4 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4" and i can load "2009-08-11 15:53:00" from cqlsh with copy command without any error

Answer (score 3):

cassandra will store `timestamp` as `2017-02-01 08:28:21+0000`. For example, if I store a `timestamp` in your described table `"TEMP_tmp".temp`:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> INSERT INTO  TEMP_tmp.temp ("Date_Time") VALUES ( toTimestamp(now()));
cassandra@cqlsh> SELECT * FROM TEMP_tmp.temp;

Date_Time
--------------------------
2017-02-01 09:14:29+0000
```

If we copy all the data to `csv`:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> COPY Temp_tmp.temp TO 'temp.csv';
```

`temp.csv` will contain:

```
2017-02-01 09:14:29+0000
```

If we `truncate` the table:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_tmp.temp;
cassandra@cqlsh> SELECT * FROM TEMP_tmp.temp;

Date_Time
--------------------------
```

Then if we import `temp.csv`:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> COPY Temp_tmp.temp FROM 'temp.csv';
Using 1 child processes

Starting copy of Temp_tmp.temp with columns [Date_Time].
Processed: 1 rows; Rate:       1 rows/s; Avg. rate:       1 rows/s
1 rows imported from 1 files in 0.746 seconds (0 skipped).
```

If you want custom date/time format, then follow [Ashraful Islam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41973366/4610541) from your question.