# Cassandra Timestamp

Tags: cassandra, copy

Tried loading the data from a cvs to a table in **Cassandra**, but facing an issue with timestamp when the values are with AM/PM. Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

```
copy <tableName> (TimeStamp,name,id) from '/dump/feb28/sample.csv'
  WITH HEADER = 'TRUE' and DATETIMEFORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %z';
```

My Date format in the csv is as follows:

```
28/03/2014 05:09:17 PM  

12/5/2014 11:55

28/03/2014 05:09:17 PM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import column value in Cassandra like one having such values "13/01/09 23:13"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972052/how-to-import-column-value-in-cassandra-like-one-having-such-values-13-01-09-23)